# Animate the Bar Chart Height using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create an automatically animated bar chart when the user scrolls into view.  Kinda look like this one http://www.adhamdannaway.com/about

I had created the chart using CSS and wanted to toggle the height percentage animation,using the jquery waypoint.
I tried to write the jquery code but it seems fail. I'm still new in jQuery and CSS so i hope someone can help enlighten me. 
Here is my attempt so far.

Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/C5v4t/

HTML code :

```
    <ul class="chart">
               <li class="axis">
            <div class="label">MVP</div>
            <div class="label">All Star</div>
            <div class="label">Slugger</div>
            <div class="label">Rookie</div>
            <div class="label">Triple A</div>
    </li>

            <li id="teal" class="teal p-95" style="visibility: visible; height: 95%; opacity: 1;">
            <div class="percent">"95"<span>%</span></div>
            <div class="skill">Karate</div></li>
                <li id="salmon" class="salmon p-90" style="visibility: visible; height: 90%; opacity: 1;">
            <div class="percent">"90"<span>%</span></div>
            <div class="skill">Taekwondo</div></li>
                <li id="peach" class="peach p-80" style="visibility: visible; height: 80%; opacity: 1;">
            <div class="percent">"80"<span>%</span></div>
            <div class="skill">Nunchucks</div></li> 
                <li id="lime" class="lime p-75" style="visibility: visible; height: 75%; opacity: 1;">
            <div class="percent">"75"<span>%</span></div>
            <div class="skill">Bow Staff</div></li>
                <li id="grape" class="grape p-40" style=" visibility: visible; height: 40%; opacity: 1;">
            <div class="percent">"40"<span>%</span></div>
            <div class="skill">Suplex</div></li>
```

CSS code:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.chart {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .chart {
    background: url("http://cl.ly/QSpc/bg-chart.png") right top repeat-x;
    height: 425px;
    margin: 0 auto emCalc(-32px);
  }
}
.chart li {
  display: block;
  height: 125px;
  padding: emCalc(25px) 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .chart li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 425px;
    margin: 0 1.8% 0 0;
    width: 15%;
  }
}
.chart .axis {
  display: none;
  top: emCalc(-45px);
  width: 8%;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .chart .axis {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
.chart .label {
  background: #cccccc;
  margin: -9px 0 71px 0;
}

.chart .percent {
  letter-spacing: -3px;
  opacity: .4;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-size: 1.875rem;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .chart .percent {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 62px;
    font-size: 3.875rem;
  }
}
.chart .percent span {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-size: 1.875rem;
}

.chart .skill {
  font-weight: 800;
  opacity: .5;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .chart .skill {
    bottom: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
.chart .teal {
  background: #4ecdc4;
  border: 1px solid #4ecdc4;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#76d8d1, #4ecdc4 70%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#76d8d1, #4ecdc4 70%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#76d8d1, #4ecdc4 70%);
}

.chart .salmon {
  background: #ff6b6b;
  border: 1px solid #ff6b6b;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#ff9e9e, #ff6b6b 70%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff9e9e, #ff6b6b 70%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ff9e9e, #ff6b6b 70%);
}

.chart .lime {
  background: #97f464;
  border: 1px solid #97f464;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#b7f794, #97f464 70%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#b7f794, #97f464 70%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#b7f794, #97f464 70%);
}

.chart .peach {
  background: #ffcd92;
  border: 1px solid #ffcd92;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#ffe4c5, #ffcd92 70%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffe4c5, #ffcd92 70%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ffe4c5, #ffcd92 70%);
}

.chart .grape {
  background: #ab64f4;
  border: 1px solid #ab64f4;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#c594f7, #ab64f4 70%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c594f7, #ab64f4 70%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#c594f7, #ab64f4 70%);
}

.chart .p-95{
    height:95%;
}

.chart .p-90{
    height:90%;
}

.chart .p-80{
    height:80%;
}

.chart .p-75{
    height:75%;
}

.chart .p-40{
    height:40%;
}
```

Script code using waypoint JS:

```
<script>
           // Animate Chart
    $('.chart').waypoint(function(event, direction) {

       $('#teal').css({'visibility':'visible', 'height': '0%'}).stop().delay(200).animate({'opacity':'1', 'height':'95%'}, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
       $('#salmon').css({'visibility':'visible', 'height': '0%'}).stop().delay(400).animate({'opacity':'1', 'height':'90%'}, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
       $('#lime').css({'visibility':'visible', 'height': '0%'}).stop().delay(600).animate({'opacity':'1', 'height':'80%'}, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
       $('#peach').css({'visibility':'visible', 'height': '0%'}).stop().delay(800).animate({'opacity':'1', 'height':'75%'}, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
       $('#grape').css({'visibility':'visible', 'height': '0%'}).stop().delay(1000).animate({'opacity':'1', 'height':'40%'}, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');

    }, {
       offset: '80%',
       triggerOnce: true

    });
        </script>
```

Comment: Create a fiddle please.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/C5v4t/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have the waypoint library at all.

Comment: You also don't have `jquery ui` so your easings won't work.

Comment: And when you add in those libraries it works just fine... http://jsfiddle.net/C5v4t/4/

Comment: Hi James! I'm so sorry. I'm actually never use jsfiddle before so i don't really know how to add the libraries. Now i see that everything work on jsfiddle i suspect a conflict with another scripts because it definitely didnt work on my project. Anyway thank you so much for helping me out and all the hassle i've caused you for adding those libraries. God bless u.